# Why this one is faster? Submission 1 vs Submission 2

Tags: c, memory, time

Question posted on Hackerearth for practice.

Write a program that prints the numbers in the given range. But for multiples of three print “**Fizz**” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “**Buzz**”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “**FizzBuzz**”. Print a new line after each string or number.

Input Format First line will be the number of testcases, T. Next line will have T integers, denoted by N.

Output Format For each testcase, print the number from 1 to N. But follow the rules given in the problem statement.

Constraints

1 <= T <= 10

**N is an integer.**

Submission 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int uc;
    scanf("%d",&uc);
    int inp[uc];
    int l=0;
    for(l=0;l<uc;l++){
        scanf("%d",&inp[l]);
    }
    for(l=0;l<uc;l++){

        int s;
        for(s=1;s<=inp[l];s++){
            if(s%5==0&&s%3==0){
                printf("FizzBuzz\n");
            }else if (s%3==0) {
                printf("Fizz\n");
            }else if(s%5==0){
                printf("Buzz\n");
            }else
            {
                printf("%d\n",s);
            }

        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Submission 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int uc;
    scanf("%d",&uc);
    int inp[uc];
    int l=0;
    for(l=0;l<uc;l++){
        scanf("%d",&inp[l]);
    }
    for(l=0;l<uc;l++){
        int k=inp[l];
        int s=1;
        for(s=1;s<=k;s++){
            if(s%3==0&&s%5==0){
                printf("FizzBuzz\n");
            }else if (s%3==0) {
                printf("Fizz\n");
            }else if(s%5==0){
                printf("Buzz\n");
            }else
            {
                printf("%d\n",s);
            }

        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

When i execute.

Step 1: Input 2

Step 2: Input 3

Step 3: Input 15

I found that Submission 2 is faster than Submission 1.

```
Submission             Time                Memory
1                      1.006  s            64KB
2                      1.0058 s            64KB
```

Now my question is why?

Comment: How is submission #1 faster when it took 200 microseconds **longer** to execute? BTW that difference is **far** within the error margin (of time measurement, non-determinism of process launching and other factors). Based on one single run, where the difference is so negligible, it's entirely unwarranted to definitively conclude that one program is "faster" than the other.

Comment: `1.0058` is faster than `1.006`. You need to know these things to be a programmer...:)

Comment: That was my silly mistake actually 2 is faster than submission 1....

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana submission 2 has a redundant `int s=1;` assignment, which obviously makes it faster ;-) Seriously now, you can't be serious if you are really asking about a 0.2 msec difference.

Comment: @dxiv yes you are right....can u post it as a answer with some deep explanation. Thank you

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana I think you missed the ";-)" smiley in my previous reply. The redundant `int s=1;` assignment (which does in fact exist in the code you posted) would most likely be optimized away by any decent compiler. But your question/claim that a 0.2 msec difference may actually be significant in any way doesn't hold. That's just noise due to whatever method you use to measure it, and whatever else happens to be executing on your computer at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a slight flaw in all tests of this variety, caused by the OS task switching among other things. If you wanted to optimise either of these programs, you should use a profiler to profile the (fully machine-optimised, e.g. using `-O3`) code and optimise the bottlenecks that the profiler identifies.

Nonetheless, it would make sense that the first solution is slightly slower than the second if you're compiling with optimisations fully disabled, because the second contains a micro-optimisation in the form of hoisting `inp[l]` outside of the inner loop so that expression is only ever evaluated once per unique value.

Comment: I think hackerearth measures time using cpu cycles used to execute the programme instead wall clock time...@Seb

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana The question uses time (measured in seconds), not CPU cycles, as a measurement. Regardless, I think you might find my hypothesis to be correct whether time or CPU cycle count is used as a measurement.

Comment: Even when i puts inp[l] outside the loop it doesn't make a difference @Seb

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana That's what I tried to explain in the first paragraph; there are more significant bottlenecks at work here, namely a task switching bias, and your experiment would also be measuring I/O as the majority of the time spent.